# How can I have multiple containers based on the same image where said image is NOT predefined? (i.e., it's built from a particular Dockerfile)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**Note:** I am using (and intend to use) a docker-compose file.

Right now, I have something like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
x-consumer: &consumer
    scale: 1
    build:
        context: . 
        dockerfile: ./consumers/Dockerfile
    environment:
        - APP_SETTINGS=config.Config
        - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
        - AWS_ACCESS_KEY=###
        - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=######

function-consumer:
    <<: *consumer
    container_name: ${NAME_PREFIX}-function_consumer
    environment:
        - CONSUMER_NAME=FunctionWorker
function-two-consumer:
    <<: *consumer
    container_name: ${NAME_PREFIX}-function_two_consumer
    environment:
        - CONSUMER_NAME=FunctionTwoWorker
```

"function" and "function-two" do different things, but effectively need almost exactly the same build. Right now, two almost identical images are built (one called function-consumer and the other function-two-consumer). Note that the image on which they're based comes from a Dockerfile I've written—not from an already predefined image.

How can I have both these containers run w/ their respective environment/name differences, but build only one image? `scale` doesn't work because I need different (and specific) container names, and using one `image` while the rest use `depend_on` doesn't work because the image file isn't pre-built, it's built according to the Dockerfile.

Any ideas?

Comment: The fact that you get two different images shouldn't matter much. Docker should still use the same base layer, and only the different env variables should be places in new layers keeping disk size and build time down.

Comment: More specifically, I'd expect to see images with names like `directoryname_function-consumer` and `directoryname_function-two-consumer`, but with the same image ID.  Re-running `docker build` should be pretty quick and just produce a new name for the same image, because of the layer-caching system.

Comment: @DavidMaze They *do* have the same image ID. Ah, I suppose what I want done was already being done, huh?